# windows server 2008 nat routing

Tags: windows, routing, nat, rras

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 with one Intel physical interface supporting VLANs. There are basically four tagged VLANs: three local ones (192.168.20.0/24 [tag: 20], 192.168.30.0/24 [tag: 30], 192.168.40.0/24 [tag: 40]) and a public one (e.g. 8.8.8.0/24 [tag: 1]) provided by ISP. ISP VLAN lets me use four different public IP-addresses for which different content-filtering rules are applied by the ISP, let these be 8.8.8.1, 8.8.8.20, 8.8.8.30 and 8.8.8.40.

Is there a way to configure Windows Server 2008 (RRAS role) so that the 192.168.20.0/24 network would be NATted to 8.8.8.20, 192.168.30.0/24 to 8.8.8.30 and so on?

P.S. I think the problem is the same if stated as follows: there are four network interfaces (three private networks and a public one), is there a way to set up NAT in a way that different networks would have access to the global net through different IP-addresses on the public interface?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem by means of `netsh routing ip nat` commands including `add interface`, `add addressrange`, `add addressmapping` while enabling automatic DNS forwarding. Using command line turned out to be more straightforward than Server Role GUI.